# Is it possible to set the System Login Screen in Windows 10 without a 3rd party tool?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to set the blue windows background image seen when logging into Windows 10.

Is it possible to set the **System Login Screen** in Windows 10 without a 3rd party tool ?

I don't want to disable it for a solid color, I would like to set it myself. 
I'm on a work machine, and I can't risk running some random 3rd party tool to do this.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: You can write the tool yourself, but guessing, thy isn't an option.  There isn't a way to do it without a tool though